# Sending variable with Tmux

Tags: bash, tmux

I have assigned a variable in `.tmux.conf`:

```
setenv -g var "Something"
```

How can I bind a key to send this variable to my terminal without needing to use <kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`send $var`?

I tried `bind -n M-q send $var Enter` which is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, but it didn't work

Comment: you can't "send" environment variables.

Comment: it's not environment variable sir, it's variable inside .tmux.conf file and I can send it to Terminal with send command in Tmux, but I want to bind a key to do that

Answer (score 1):

```
setenv -g var "Something"
bind -n M-q run-shell "tmux send #{var}" # or
bind -n M-q run-shell 'tmux send ${var}'
```

It's important to understand that Tmux's "global environment" is not the same as the "process environment" of the Tmux server.  From the man page:

[GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#GLOBAL_AND_SESSION_ENVIRONMENT)

> When the server is started, tmux copies the environment into the *global environment*

Honestly, this is a bit odd to me.  I think we all expect Tmux to parse global (`-g`) variables into its own process the same way that a `.bashrc` would be sourced into a shell, but it doesn't work that way.

The "global environment" is the environment that Tmux applies to *all sessions that it creates*, not that of Tmux itself.

We can demonstrate that `var` is not part of the Tmux server's environment with:

```bsh
$ strings /proc/$(pgrep -xo "tmux: server")/environ
$ strings /proc/$(pgrep -xo "tmux: server")/environ | grep Something
```

It's actually not even part of the Tmux *client's* environment either:

```bsh
$ strings /proc/$(pgrep -xo "tmux: client")/environ | grep Something
```

However, it *is* part of the environment that Tmux passes into newly created sessions:

```bsh
$ strings /proc/$$/environ | grep Something
var=Something
```

So to utilize the value that you set in your `.tmux.conf`, we can use `run-shell` to start a *new* shell, which Tmux will populate with the global environment, and run the `tmux send ...` command there.